# Generate a random time for model queryset

Tags: python, django

I am trying to generate random time beetween 20 hours a go and now, and assign it to a all queryset pass 24H.

here what i make:

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
from blogs.models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

def rotate_time():
    now = timezone.now()
    day_pass = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    qs = Post.objects.filter(created__lt=day_pass)
    number = qs.count()
    lst = []
    for _ in range(number):
        for t in [fake.date_time_between(start_date='-20h', end_date='now')]:
            lst.append(t)
    for i in lst:
        print(i) # this work fin until now <==
        x = 0
        while x < len(lst): 
            time = i[x+1]
            if qs.exists():
                for item in qs:
                    item.pud_date_rotation = time
                    item.save()
```

TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

Comment: could you add the model code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong here.

Firstly the one that causes the error: `i` is a `datetime` not a list or any other subscriptable type. This is why `i[x+1]` throws an error.

Secondly if you're trying to iterate over all items in the queryset and give them each a random time, why not just iterate over the queryset?

```py
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
from blogs.models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

def rotate_time():
    now = timezone.now()
    day_pass = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    qs = Post.objects.filter(created__lt=day_pass)

    for post in qs:
        post.pud_date_rotation = fake.date_time_between(start_date='-20h', end_date='now')
        post.save()
```

if you want to give all posts the same time, just calculate the time before the loop like so:

```py
def rotate_time():
    now = timezone.now()
    day_pass = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    qs = Post.objects.filter(created__lt=day_pass)
    
    time = fake.date_time_between(start_date='-20h', end_date='now')
    for post in qs:
        post.pud_date_rotation = time
        post.save()
```

Comment: Yes, i was trying to iterate over all items in the queryset and give them each a random time, you save my life , i test it  and it work, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

In this section of code

```
for i in lst:
        print(i) # this work fin until now <==
        x = 0
        while x < len(lst): 
            time = i[x+1]
```

you put `time = i[x+1]` but `i` is a datetime object not a list so isn't indexed. This is causing the error.

I think you meant to put `time = lst[x+1]`.

Giving you

```
for i in lst:
        print(i) # this work fin until now <==
        x = 0
        while x < len(lst): 
            time = lst[x+1]
```

Sidenote: you're `while` loop will run forever because you don't increment the value of `x` anywhere inside it. Your code might need some refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you try to access a datetime object:

```
time = i[x+1]
```

but the `list` of datetime ojects is called `lst` in your code. Maybe you meant

```
while x < len(lst):
    time = lst[x+1]
```

I suggest renaming the variables so you see what they are when you read them `datetimes_list` for example. Also there is no stop condition (will run forever). I suggest something like:

```
while x < len(lst):
    time = lst[x+1]
    ... your other code ...
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why am I even doing thins since question was answered, but still...

```
from datetime import timedelta
from itertools import islice

from blogs.models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
from faker import Faker


fake = Faker()

def rotate_time():
    now = timezone.now()
    day_pass = now - timedelta(hours=24)
    
    qs = Post.objects.filter(created__lt=day_pass).iterator()
    while True:
        posts = list(islice(qs, 2000))
        if not posts:
            break
        for post in posts:
            post.pud_date_rotation = fake.date_time_between(start_date='-20h', end_date='now')
        Post.objects.bulk_update(posts, ['pud_date_rotation'])
```

Comment: still, your code look find but i use django 2.0 and bulk_update it's new in django 2.2

Comment: Django 2.0 is labeled as an insecure version. See the header here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/